# Implement JSON response for Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have this security config that when a "resource" is accessed in my application Controller returns a Spring Login form:

```
<http auto-config="true" create-session="stateless" use-expressions="true">
     <intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
     <intercept-url pattern="/admin*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
</http>
```

However, what I need is to return a JSON response and not a login from. When I try to set `auto-config="false"` I get this error:

```
No AuthenticationEntryPoint could be established.
```

What config do I need to set in my application so it will provide a JSON response instead of a login form.

Comment: You have two problems here: 1) if you don't use `auto-config="true"`, you should [provide AuthenticationEntryPoint](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-entry-point-ref) by yourself; 2) to return JSON from Controller use [`@ResponseBody`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-ann-responsebody) annotation, add Jackson to classpath and return `Map<String, Object>` from controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for default-target-url="/url" specify on the controller @ResponseBody.